# VBA started to ask to dimension variables that wasn't dimensioned previously in a code that was working before

Tags: excel, vba, object, variables, declare

I have a routine that replicates excel files from a consolidated. These excel files replicated are named by a list of names in a sheet. I use the "for" function to do it in a cycle from the first name until the last one in the list present in a sheet. Last year I used the code and vba wasn't asking to declare all the variables. And now, when I tried to use, it started to ask me to declare. I declared but something is missing in the code that I coundn't find an answer and vba is giving me a msgbox:

### ***"Object variable or With block variable not set"***.

I never read something similar to this. Follow the code below and which line the problem is occuring:

````
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim destino As String, gestor, Arquivo2
Dim Arquivo As Workbook
Dim UltimaLinhaGestor As Integer, i, UltimaLinhaBases, UltimaLinhaArquivo, CC


CC = 8

destino = "C:\Users\arno\Documents\"
UltimaLinhaGestor = Sheets("Farol").Cells(Rows.Count, CC).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 3 To UltimaLinhaGestor
        gestor = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Farol").Cells(i, CC).Value
        
'##########     HERE     ##########
        Arquivo = "Orçamento 2021 - " & gestor
'##########     HERE     ##########       
 
        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (destino & Arquivo & ".xlsm")
        
        Workbooks.Open (destino & Arquivo & ".xlsm"), False
            
        Workbooks(Arquivo).Activate

    Next i```
````

Comment: `Dim Arquivo As String`.

Comment: Your use of parentheses in `ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (destino & Arquivo & ".xlsm")` and `Workbooks.Open (destino & Arquivo & ".xlsm"), False` is problematic too.

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of all modules. This forces you to declare all variables.

Comment: FYI that code as-posted will always have raise a run-time error (assuming it enters the For loop), so it's difficult to imagine how it could have worked previously.

Answer (score 0):

### Create Workbooks From List

- Adjust the values in the **const**ants section as you see fit.
- The variable names might be lame but the point is to make them descriptive. And my knowledge of Portuguese is what I learned using Google Translate to write this code.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub consolidar()
    
    ' Constants
    Const camArq As String = "C:\Users\arno\Documents\" ' File Path
    Const orcAno As String = "Orçamento 2021 - "        ' Budget/Year
    Const extArq As String = ".xlsm"                    ' File Extensiom
    Const nomePlanilhaFonte As String = "Farol"         ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const primeiraLinha As Long = 3                     ' First Row
    Const colunaFonte As Variant = 8 ' e.g. 1 or "A"    ' Source Column
    Dim livroFonte As Workbook                          ' Source Workbook Object
    Set livroFonte = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet (planilhaFonte).
    Dim planilhaFonte As Worksheet
    Set planilhaFonte = livroFonte.Worksheets(nomePlanilhaFonte)
    
    ' Calculate Last Row (ultimaLinha) containing data in Source Column.
    Dim ultimaLinha As Long
    ultimaLinha = planilhaFonte.Cells(planilhaFonte.Rows.Count, colunaFonte) _
                               .End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Speed up the code. You won't be able to see what the code is doing.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Declare additional variables to be used in the "For Next" loop.
    Dim livroDestino As Workbook, i As Long, gestor As String
    Dim nomeCompleto As String
    
    ' In source column, loop from first to last source row of source workbook.
    For i = primeiraLinha To ultimaLinha
        
        ' Define 'FullName' (nomeCompleto) of the to be created
        ' destination workbook, to be used with "SaveCopyAs" and "Open".
        gestor = planilhaFonte.Cells(i, colunaFonte).Value
        nomeCompleto = camArq & orcAno & gestor & extArq
        
        ' Save source workbook as current destination workbook.
        ' "DisplayAlerts" is used to overwrite the possible existing files
        ' without "Excel" 'complaining'.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        livroFonte.SaveCopyAs nomeCompleto
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        ' Open current destination workbook.
        Set livroDestino = Workbooks.Open(nomeCompleto)
            
        ' Do stuff in current destination workbook.
        With livroDestino
            
            ' e.g. Print name to Immediate window (CTRL+G).
            Debug.Print .Name
            ' or:
            '.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Test"
            ' ...
            
            ' Finally close current destination workbook.
            .Close True ' True means save changes.
        
        End With
    
    Next i

    ' Stop speeding up the code and refresh screen.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform user-
    MsgBox "Sucesso"
 
End Sub
```